# Debugging C++ project in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I wrote a C# project in which I use a C++ dll (also written by me). I am trying to debug this dll function from my C# solution.

I have added C++ project to C# solution and manage its output - that's ok. But I could not get into the dll functions (break points not loaded).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using a version of Visual Studio that is not Express, you should be able to allow native C++ debugging by checking an option in the properties pane of the project you are running. Go to Project Properties -> Debug -> Enable unmanaged code debugging.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will want to make sure that your native DLL was compiled and linked in debug mode. Though I don't work with the Visual Studio IDE much, the command line options you want are `/Zi` for `cl.exe` and `/DEBUG` for `link.exe`. This should result in the DLL being built with debug symbols enabled, and a `.pdb` file being generated. You should then be able to attach to the process as usual (you may have to do this from the Visual C++ debugger---again, I don't work much with the IDE) and set breakpoints on functions in the DLL.

Answer (score 0):

Samuel Slade's answer is correct with one clarification:

I was trying to debug into an ATL/MFC C++ COM object from some C# code using Visual Studio 2010. I had a separate Solution for each project and could not make it work. When I put both projects into one Solution and *enabled unmanaged code debugging* as directed above, it worked wonderfully.

So cram both projects into one Solution and it should work.